# Create Firestore database documents from Postman

Tags: json, rest, api, google-cloud-firestore, postman

I'm trying to create multiple documents at once in a Firestore collection with configuration purposes. I can create documents one by one sending from Postman:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "category":{"stringValue": "Configs"},
        "order":{"integerValue":"3"}
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is some way to create multiple documents sending something like this:

```
{
    "batch": [
        {
            "fields": {
                "categoria": {
                    "stringValue": "Configurações"
                },
                "ordem": {
                    "integerValue": "3"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "categoria": {
                    "stringValue": "Configurações"
                },
                "ordem": {
                    "integerValue": "3"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone say if is it possible? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you manage to get this right?

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below should work.

Although it is an "update" action is creates new documents as well if they don't exist. The document ID must be provided, it cannot be auto generated using the commit endpoint.

I was able to get my use case to work after viewing this [response](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/commit) detailing use of [commit](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/commit).

API Endpoint: https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectID/databases/(default)/documents:commit

```
{
    "writes": [
        {
            "update": {
                "name": "projects/projectID/databases/(default)/documents/test/ExistingDocumentID1",
                "fields": {
                    "comment": {
                        "stringValue": "Hello World!"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "update": {
                "name": "projects/projectID/databases/(default)/documents/test/NewManualDocumentID2",
                "fields": {
                    "comment": {
                        "stringValue": "Happy Birthday!"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```