# Cloud Firestore add multiple document using REST API - PHP

Tags: php, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add multiple documents in one connection using google cloud firestore REST API. I can do this for single documant, but when I try to add more than one, I get an error.

The code I use to add a single document

```
$data = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Field1' => array(
            'stringValue' => 'deneme'
        ),
        'Field2' => array(
            'stringValue' => 'deneme2'
        )
    ),
);

//$data = array_values($data);
$data_string = json_encode($data); 
echo $data_string;


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/***/databases/(default)/documents/deneme/DEN6600011/TARIH');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);   

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: Bearer (MY-API-KEY)'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$sonuc = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $sonuc;
```

I tried to do this by changing the data array like this but at that time I get an error.

```
$data = array(
    "documents" => array(
    array('fields' => array(
        'Field1' => array(
            'stringValue' => 'deneme'
        ),
        'Field2' => array(
            'stringValue' => 'deneme2'
        )
    )),
    array('fields' => array(
        'Field1' => array(
            'stringValue' => 'deneme'
        ),
        'Field2' => array(
            'stringValue' => 'deneme2'
        )
    )),
));
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"documents\" at 'document': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "document",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"documents\" at 'document': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried it in other ways, but I got errors in all of them. How can I add multiple data using single JSON with REST API?

Answer (score 1):

You could use update to create multiple document
the update operation will create the document that does not exist, you should also provide the document id.
A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58311318/8191648)

Alternatively, you could try using the [PHP Library](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/libraries#php).

Using [create](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.12.2/firestore/documentreference?method=create) or [set](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.12.2/firestore/documentreference?method=set) you will be able to create multiple document in one request.

As for the issue with your current way, this most-likely due to the json request body not being well defined.